# Get id of div where i drag an element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have 2 or more divs droppable and a place where a have some products that i drag&drop into this 2 or more divs.
After a drop an element in one of the divs i want to move that element in other div drippable and whant to know what's that div id.

I search on google and i found this :
- `$(event.target).attr("id")` - this one give me the id of the element that i move
- `$(this).parent().attr('id')` - this one give me the id of the div container where my element was

After i move the element i want to know the id of the div where i drop the element.

Comment: Are you using jquery ui drag+drop? Show your code please.

Comment: yes. my script is like this : $( ".existaaa" ).draggable({ snap: true, snapMode: "outer", parent : ".continut"  },
    
  {
   stop: function(event, ui)
         {  }  }};

Comment: can you post your javascript through which you are moving the element?

Comment: yes. that script i use it for the elements that have been saved to the databases. when i reload the page i have some elements in one div and some elements in other div. If i move one element from one div to other i want to know the id of the id where i drop the element ( the new parent :) ).

Comment: `$(this).parent().attr('id')` try this after moving the element

Comment: i try it but it give me the id of the first div. the one in that the element is positioned. i'm not sure if i wrote the code coret : $( ".existaaa" ).draggable({ snap: true, snapMode: "outer" },
    
  {
   stop: function(event, ui)
         {  
      
           console.log($(this).parent().attr('id')); 
    
           }
   
   
  }
   
  );

Comment: may be this can help : http://conta.md/rafturi/kae/test.php?id=13

Comment: i think it could help me if i put a button next to each one of the container div that will give me an array of the element insite the div. but how can i "read" the all the elements that are inside a div?

Comment: @Corneliu- have you tried `Daniel` updated answer..i think that will do the trick..if not it will be better if you go with Docs..you will find something of your use

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. i'm new to Jquery. Lets make it useful whit this link : http://conta.md/rafturi/kae/tester.php ; i have 2 div - container , one div clone draggable white bg and one black div draggable that comes from mysql (let's say). I want that when i move the black div from the curent div parent to the next one to have a variable insite stop:function that give me de id of the new div. plase show me what exactly to do. inside this stop:function i have 2 variables :  one gives me the id of the curent div and ones give me de id of the element i move (black div).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `id` of the [`draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [`droppable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) in the `drop` callback function - see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YdcWt/)

Taking @jensgram's advice ([Utilizing the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element)) for speed of `this.id` over `.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

try this--

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
   drop: function() {
     $(this).attr('id');
   }
});
```

and have a look at this post- [some info about drag and drop](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html)